# How to get the exact loading time of website in jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

Just wanna know if this scenario is possible in jmeter:

I will create a website using docker image then i will have to check the exact accessibility time(from creating up to launching/checking the site). Once the requirement is met, the timer will stop and it will give me the exact time on when it is actually up. Also, in the view result tree, i only want to get the last successful status. The View Result Tree will only show the last successful status and will disregard the failed status. This is the sample of my thread that i am using: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oathw.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to discard non-successful results you can do this using [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the following Groovy code:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

where `prev` is a shorthand for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) and [setIgnore() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) tells the listener to ignore the result in case of failure.

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)